# Can we unit test a sequelize model without a database connection?

Tags: sequelize.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var player = sequelize.define('player', {
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    mess: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

here it gives me error that model is not defined.but the model is already defined.

Comment: Do you want to validate the model created or do you want to mock this for some kind of unit testing?

Comment: yes, i want to mock this for unit testing.

Comment: I would suggest you to use [sequelize-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-mock) instead to do the mocking of the database models

Comment: thanks buddy, it works !

Comment: Perfect. I've left an answer to this question. While the default example has a `user` model, you could easily replace it with the `player` model that you're planning to test.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to mock the sequelize model for unit testing, the best way to do that would be to use [sequelize-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-mock). The version while writing the answer is 0.10.2

Here's a sample of how you could use it [from their documentation](https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
// Import the mock library

var SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');

// Setup the mock database connection
var DBConnectionMock = new SequelizeMock();

// Define our Model
var UserMock = DBConnectionMock.define('users', {
        'email': 'email@example.com',
        'username': 'blink',
        'picture': 'user-picture.jpg',
    }, {
        instanceMethods: {
            myTestFunc: function () {
                return 'Test User';
            },
        },
    });

// You can also associate mock models as well
var GroupMock = DBConnectionMock.define('groups', {
    'name': 'My Awesome Group',
});

UserMock.belongsTo(GroupMock);

// From there we can start using it like a normal model
UserMock.findOne({
    where: {
        username: 'my-user',
    },
}).then(function (user) {
    // `user` is a Sequelize Model-like object
    user.get('id');         // Auto-Incrementing ID available on all Models
    user.get('email');      // 'email@example.com'; Pulled from default values
    user.get('username');   // 'my-user'; Pulled from the `where` in the query

    user.myTestFunc();      // Will return 'Test User' as defined above

    user.getGroup();        // Will return a `GroupMock` object
});
```

Comment: Why recreating User model again? in unit test we need actual model to be tested without connection to DB. actually connection should be mocked not model definition.